# Why does Android NoSuchMethodException occurs at AlertDialog.Builder's setOnDismissListener

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting a `NoSuchMethodException` when using `setOnDismissListener` on `Dialog` in Android on a device with 4.1.2.

The same code is working on the emulator with version 4.2.2.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
   .setTitle(R.string.select_province)
   .setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
       //== other stuff
    }
}).show();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `setOnDismissListener` method is available only from API 17. Your emulator is running on API 17, your device isn't (it actually runs on API 16). All the API levels are enumerated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

Answer (score 27):

A workaround to this issue is to just first create the dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(R.string.select_province).create();
```

and then set the listener directly to the dialog:

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener( new OnDismissListener() {
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
   //== other stuff
} );
```

then if you also want to show it:

```
dialog.show();
```

the result is the same and all these methods are supported since API 1.

AlertDialog.[setOnDismissListener (DialogInterface.OnDismissListener listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29)

AlerDialog.Builder.[create()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this answer while using a DialogFragment, Mario's method will result in an IllegalStateException.  In this case, Rather than using setOnDismissListener as suggested, one should override the Fragment's existing onDismiss method.